# How to create and store data in a JSON file on angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I want to create a json file ,set it in local storage. Into that json file , need to insert username and password from user.

Comment: You can not create a JSON file with Angular, as the angular is the frontend application. but you can store JSON type ouput in the local storage. and I would suggest you to keep that data encoded

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save the password in the local storage. It is not that secure. Also, you don't need a JSON file and this is not Angular specific.

Use

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "Mirshad");
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem("username");
```

You can store objects too, but they will be returned as string and you need to use

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("username")).
```